# Lodash isEqual function is causing application freeze

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am creating a react component, and it do the default export as in the following line:

> React.memo(MyReactComponent, isEqual)

The isEqual function is from lodash lib. My application constantly tries to update the component props at 10 Hz. However, from time to time my application freezes executing the isEqual function from lodash. Do you guys have ideas for what could cause it?

Comment: how many props does the component have? how deep is the nesting of these props? can the props instead be immutable and compared normally via reference? 10Hz is an update every 0.1 seconds, does it need to be so often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript objects can (in theory) have cyclic references, so this might crash `lodash.isEqual()`.

Another scenario is that the objects you compare contain React components, which [might crash](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19811) `lodash.isEqual` too.

But whatever the specific reason might be in your particular case, it is usually not a good idea to use deep object comparison in the `areEqual()` function of `React.memo`. After all, you are using memoization to prevent costly re-renders. If do costly prop comparison instead, you don't win a lot.

A better approach would be to optimize the code then generates/modifies the props of your component und use `useMemo()` to prevent unnecessary updates to your state. If you do this consistently, you don't need to provide `React.memo` with a custom `areEquals` function anymore because the shallow comparison that React will do per default will suffice.

Comment: Thanks, my problem is exactly the second thing you mentioned. My object has a prop which is a react component. I just don't get why I could not do this and what a react component has that causes this problem in particular.